# Generic function gets type even if it is not provided

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why a generic function gets the generic type automatically, without providing anything to it.

```
type T<G = Record<string, any>> = {
     id: keyof G
     label: string
     somethingElse?: string
}
```

This function returns an object that has a special property `id`, that should have a type `"random"` if `source` property is not passed to it. If `source` is passed, the returned `id` should get the type of `source`

```
const element = <ID extends string = 'random'>({ source }: { source?: ID } = {}) =>
    ({
        id: (source || 'random') as ID,
        label: 'Element1',
    }) as const satisfies T  
    // I don't want the return type to be "T", I want what it returns to satisfy "T".
    // as you see I dont provide "somethingElse" key here, so I don't want it in the return type

type Data = { a: string; b: number }
```

This gives me the exact error I want, but only if I use variables:

```
const el1 = element()                   // el1 gets type { readonly id: "random";  readonly label: "Element1"; }
const el2 = element({source: 'b'})     // el2 gets type { readonly id: "b";  readonly label: "Element1"; }
const el3 = element({source: 'else'})   // el3 gets type { readonly id: "else";  readonly label: "Element1"; }

const b: T<Data>[] = [el, el2, el3]   // el1 and el3 invalid, el2 valid. It is all correct
```

But why this is valid when I directly use it without variable? It should throw an error

```
const a: T<Data>[] = [element()]   
// No generic or property is provided to it "element()", 
// why the return type of "element()" is { readonly id: keyof Data; readonly label: "Element1"; } ??
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBUA8BxWBeWAlaBjA9gE4AmiAzqAQJYB2A5gDSwCG14AfG%20rAN7Cz%20xKRAFywA1tHB4AZrGR8BAGyYAjaItHkqdBf1J4AttFAALGrQCii0tAD8miueABfEPmrlY66EeqguiACSACJeAB6g0NREpLBa5lwA5AQsRIaJbAAU3HF4AK4EOHDOojn6BUX2sCGwzlzczgCU6Gy62boCgiKwmeWFcAA%20A7DJqenNTLEh9B1KquqiiVY%20UaAAjIkzAk3Mse6epEyglKTSlNCx8Py6APQ31bBp1In%20AO4s-qZwBMYF1LAQGAAvCwNSwABE8HBjECsHefjhJiOgn8P1Af1ioBBh2Op3AEKhADpbvdJrApHk4tA4LCnv5IAQ8AA3IRwcH6IymcxWGzg8SSWAmaA-Rj6B5PF5wj4owT-L6wNF-AFQaAgQFwYJHJj1ZgObS0ADcoNE1DyBjUBFqIDuCDMsVolCZF1gRgBQvCTBw-mFjMtsPhoGEwH23sUay43l8oEyzU6cYEwBt6nDtGMmJVPAV0CYT0U%20KEonBKWihnBRqzObw1DzsGUag0EOWUbWZdqhNgwarnnUACYI4oVn5sn0iosVIkdtck4o%206nQOmgTkfpXq-nuuCVK2K7n8XWFo2B83W85iSGvIoAMz9wfR7gj6CLdQ2CexjvTq9zhdwJfZnddQtPtAW7Ln%20e4NuCTarC2Ronm4Xb%20CoohIJqoBMGwADaAC6XDocmjC9vhl7Yfw07hqk55XjQTJMIoQiEX21G0UQ7aBP4JzMIoiiwPgBA-F6ICJvcABCeRvCY%20JcrE7GMUIiJROKlB8aANZ5DYMqvJQpj5P41FUKoA62LY1T%20KQJj5IoRBuoyrzMP8PqEJ2Hj%20EwSGIChaFYThkarDGxFvvcAByIKptQwqUDgsCELADJ4DABAQIIsQxSyRDQJZWIyuC3lDo00L%20YiEnuoqBByhmMgQtl0a5YlmYgVWNYFvyUiyO5Rp1autbzOBkF%20NBtSwIZsBAA)

Comment: TS can infer generics from return types. In some sense it *is* provided because the compiler expects `[element()]` to be of type `T<Data>[]`.  If you don't want TS to do that for `element()`, you can use `NoInfer` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzqdRm) to block inference.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems like this will fix it, but... Is it possible to use something for an older version of TS, like 5.0.4 ?

Comment: Yes, you can roll your own `NoInfer<T>` that works for some use cases, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nrolam). Do I need to worry about that in my answer? Dependencies on older versions of TypeScript get stale very quickly.

Comment: No need to mention that, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can [use function return types as inference targets](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#return-types-as-inference-targets), meaning that a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function can have its type parameters inferred by the contextual type of its return as well as by the known types of its arguments. In

```
const a: T<Data>[] = [element()]
```

the compiler expects `[element()]` to be of type `T<Data>[]` and thus for `element()` to be of type `T<Data>` and thus for `ID` to be `keyof Data` and there's no error.

---

If you don't like that and you want the return type *not* to be used as an inference site, you can use [the `NoInfer` utility type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-4/#the-noinfer-utility-type) to block the inference from that position:

```
const element = <ID extends string = 'random'>({ source }: { source?: ID } = {}) =>
   ({
       id: (source || 'random') as NoInfer<ID>, // <-- here
       label: 'Element1',
   }) as const satisfies T
```

In cases where `ID` was not being inferred from the return type, this should have no effect, and all your other examples are the same:

```
const el1 = element()             
// el1 gets type { readonly id: "random";  readonly label: "Element1"; }. 
const el2 = element({source: 'b'})   
// el2 gets type { readonly id: "b";  readonly label: "Element1"; }.
const el3 = element({source: 'else'})   
// el3 gets type { readonly id: "else";  readonly label: "Element1"; }.
const b: T<Data>[] = [el1, el2, el3]   // el1 and el3 invalid, el2 valid.
```

But now you get the desired error in your last example, since the `T<Data>` context doesn't affect `ID`. And since `ID` now has no inference site at all, it falls back to the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `"random"`:

```
const a: T<Data>[] = [element()]  // error!
// Type '{ readonly id: "random"; readonly label: "Element1"; }' 
// is not assignable to type 'T<Data>'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBUA8BxWBeWAlaBjA9gE4AmiAzqAQJYB2A5gDSwCG14AfG+rAN7Cz+xKRAFywA1tHB4AZrGR8BAGyYAjaItHkqdBf1J4AttFAALGrQCii0tAD8miueABfEPmrlY66EeqguiACSACJeAB6g0NREpLBa5lwA5AQsRIaJbAAU3HF4AK4EOHDOojn6BUX2sCGwzlzczgCU6Gy62boCgiKwmeWFcAA+A7DJqenNTLEAcniB1NLQBEHBbIwA9GuwiAC028xERLCmlKQdSqrqoolWPlGgAIyJ9LpNzLHunqRMoCfSlNCxeD8EAQGCwYLfJj1ZgObS0ADcsBUomoeQMagItRAGwQZlitEoADcAbAjEcTHBoGEmDh-IsCIRqrAAO4sUDCYAfOmKe5cby+UCZZqdEUCYA49S82jGWKguA5AjQJhpaiKcBdUQAIhS0UMmsRsEVyrwqvVyjUGlgmpuAvu+tqADpYJyTZ51AAmPmKW5+bJ9IpXFSJV7AiWKT3S0CyqDyw1KlVqjVWlT2uPG02wc2XK02u52xHOB0ujzcgDMXp9gu4-ugV3UNmDwudYfLkejYIV8ZNiaEWvr0FTRoTZoulut3tt9sLxc8yIQiAhoCYbAA2gBdLgryWMD07xSljf8MO81JefeCaiEpiKIR7z1Xm9EJ1uV3+JiiJCL5frzf8u5Cw8JQIBkCAAQnFTZ4BjEZO3THtum1MYDHtIduxHC0tVzPx81qRJm02E5YGoPA31IUhKFoahVG9I48COaDEk-SE2ESIsgA)